# Google maps displaying other side of the planet

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have literally been trying anything and everything, but the map displays somewhere in Antarctica, when the coordinates that I am receiving, are for cities in the US.

The following is the code that inits the map:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {

// eslint-disable-next-line
function initTest() {
var fastestCitiesApi = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('fastestCitiesApi').value);
console.log(fastestCitiesApi);
var tempLatLng = fastestCitiesApi[0]['latLng'];
console.log(tempLatLng);
var latLng = tempLatLng.split(',');
console.log('latLng[0]: ' + latLng[0]);
console.log('latLng[1]: ' + latLng[1]);
const myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng({ lat: parseFloat(latLng[0]), lng: parseFloat(latLng[1]) });
const mapOptions = {
  zoom: 4,
  center: myLatLng
};
const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('fastest_cities_map'), mapOptions);
new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map,
  title: 'somewhere',
});
}

initTest();
});
```

As you can see by the following screen shot of the console is showing, that the coordinates are 36, 78 - which when I do a look up on google for Boydton, VA - those are the coordinates that is returned - [link to google search for Boydton, VA lat long](https://www.google.com/search?q=lat%20long%20Boydton%2C%20VA&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)
[image]

As you can see by the screen shot, I have zero errors. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you have the latitude and longitude reversed.

Comment: Double check your values.  The Latitude should be 36°, and the  Longitude: -78°   I'm guessing your Longitude is 78 and it should be a negative value.  If that doesn't work, try reversing to Lon and Lat.  In mapping, the Lon comes before the Lat.  Having the Lon and Lat  in the wrong order will put the map projection far, far away from where it should be.

Comment: thank you @Gray for pointing out that it is -78. When I looked up Boydton, VA lat long, google shows is to be 36.6676° N, 78.3875° W. Is the "W" indicating that I should have a negative number  -78?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Gray pointing out that the long should be negative, the rest of the array loaded up the markers as expected.

Here's the final code:

```
    $(window).on('load', function() {
  // eslint-disable-next-line

  function initTest() {
    /* init vars */
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('fastest_cities_map'));
    var fastestCitiesApi = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('fastestCitiesApi').value);
    // console.log(fastestCitiesApi);
    var tempLatLng = '';
    var latLng = [];

    var markerOptionsArray = new Array();
    var latlngArray = new Array();

    var myLat = new Array();
    var myLng = new Array();
    var markers = [];
    var nameArray = [];
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth: 350});
    /* create arrays for markers */
    for(var item in fastestCitiesApi) {
      tempLatLng = fastestCitiesApi[item]['latLng'];
      nameArray.push(fastestCitiesApi[item]['city']);
    // console.log(tempLatLng);
      latLng = tempLatLng.split(',');
      myLat.push(latLng[0]);
      myLng.push(latLng[1]);
    // console.log('latLng[0]: ' + latLng[0]);
    // console.log('latLng[1]: ' + latLng[1]);

      markers.push({
        lat: myLat[item],
        lng: myLng[item],
        name: nameArray[item],
      });
    }
  // console.log('markers: ' + JSON.stringify(markers));

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (var v=0; v<markers.length; v++)
    {
      var secheltLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[v].lat, markers[v].lng);
      var myOptions = {
        content: markers[v].name
        ,boxStyle: {
          border: "none"
          ,textAlign: "center"
          ,fontSize: "12pt"
          ,width: "120px"
        }
        ,disableAutoPan: true
        ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-50, 0)
        ,position: secheltLoc
        ,closeBoxURL: ""
        ,isHidden: false
        ,pane: "mapPane"
        ,enableEventPropagation: true
      };


      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[v].lat, markers[v].lng),
        map: map,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[v].lat, markers[v].lng)
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, v) {
        return function () {
          infowindow.setContent(markers[v].name);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, v));

      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.close();
        marker.open = false;
      });

      bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(markers[v].lat, markers[v].lng));

      myLatLng = markers[v].lat+','+markers[v].lng;
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
  // alert(google.maps.Map);
    initTest();
});
```

The following is a screen shot of the result of the eight city array:
[image: screen shot of the google map]